# Can BlackBerry Devices upgrade to the latest BlackBerry OS?

Tags: blackberry, operating-system, upgrade, blackberry-os-v5

This might sound like a noob question, but here it goes anyway. Can BlackBerry devices upgrade themselves to the latest version of the BB software?

So in the same way that an iPhone 3G can upgrade to iOS 4.0, could (for example) a BlackBerry Curve upgrade itself to BlackBerry OS 6? Or could something like a BB 7100i upgrade to a newer OS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to update your device is to connect it to a computer running the BlackBerry Desktop Software. It will check for any updates and install them for you. The available updates for your device is not as simple as on the iPhone as some devices won't support the latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the device and the OS version you wish to upgrade to.

You might be better asking this question in the blackberry support forum

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry devices can upgrade to new OS if the devices support OS Upgrade feature.

Comment: Thanks Ashwini. Is there a website where I can find which devices support OS upgrade?